# Responsive website vs. Android/iOS/Firefox/WinPhone App

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

That’s great BUT… *what you really need is a responsive website not (at least) two native mobile apps*.

Advantages: Reduced development effort, fewer maintenance costs, and pretty much the same benefit – which is accessing stack exchange websites on smaller screen devices. By entering the native app world your building all from scratch (some people are already asking about what will happen to LaTeX characters on these native apps).

You don’t even have to make it fully responsive, just let the questions/answers' text wrap according to the window’s width.

Scenario: **a developer using a 13'inch laptop**, half the screen with browser opened on stackoverflow and the other half with the code editor. This group of people **will continue to endure the pain of horizontal scrolling or window switching all day long.** What do you have to say to these people?

Comment: *"what you really need is"* that's just your opinion. And I don't mean that in a bad way, the debate between native apps and responsive websites is huge and neither of them is clearly better than the other.

Comment: I'm not going to get into the App vs Responsive website debate, but for your hypothetical scenario, I'd say get an external monitor :)

Comment: get a second monitor or get a tablet and install the app xD | @Stijn I understand this is a subjective question, but since StackOverflow is a developer website and developers don't develop on mobile devices, I guess a responsive design would be more effective. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: You do know that they also have a mobile website? Try the "mobile" link in the footer.

Comment: @animuson no, I didn't know. Please give that answer to my question so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: One of the benefits of apps is notifications.